# Should I create two tag managers for two different websites under the same domain?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I own two websites under the same domain eg. abc.com and abc.com/xyz. Both of them are hosted on different servers. So, should I create two separate tag manager accounts and thus two properties in Universal Analytics OR two tag manager accounts and one property in UA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should.

If the two website are serving different content or you want to see the data individually. You should separate to two GTM and GA.

Comment: So should I separate the property in Universal analytics too? so far the company has been using the same property but two different tag manager accounts. This is causing some problems, like recording conversions or connecting with Google ads.

Comment: Yes you should. For both Universal Analytics or GA4. Because it is separated websites.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I have another question related to the Search Console, we have separate properties for two websites on the google search console, but the main URL viz. abc.com also collects data for the other website viz. abc.com/xyz. Do you know the reason why?

Comment: Does the abc.com/xyz also have the same google verify code?